# how to end process the program using a key in assemble language

Tags: assembly, tasm

Lowercase to uppercase vice versa. Characters. When press "X" the process will end. Here's my code:

```
.model small
.stack
.data
msg db 'Enter a character ',10,'$'
.code

start: 


mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov ah,9
mov dx,offset msg
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h


Y:
cmp al,'a'
jb X
cmp al,'z'
ja unchanged
sub al,20h
jmp unchanged


X:
cmp al,'A'
jb unchanged
cmp al,'Z'
ja unchanged
add al,20h
unchanged:
mov ah,2


mov dl,al
int 21h



jmp start
mov cx,10


exit:

mov ah,4ch
int 21h


end start
```

Comment: cmp al,'x'
je Y
jmp exit
mov cx,10

i tried to add this code but the output is opposite on the right output

Answer (score 2):

To exit on a capital **X** test for it at the *X:* label.
You don't need the `mov cx,10`. It will never get executed.

```
X:
cmp al,'X'
je Exit
cmp al,'A'
```

To also exit on a lowercase **x** add similar code at the *Y:* label.

```
Y:
cmp al,'x'
je Exit
cmp al,'a'
```